I would like to modify a specific widget among several of the same type
It's my first try on flutter and dart for a personal project. For context, I want to create an application to play darts (the game not the langage :p).
I want to have n widget representing the n current player and their score. Here is my current code :
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:dart_e/pages/home/home.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

//________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
class Game extends StatelessWidget {
  const Game({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => MyAppState(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Bonjour',
        theme: ThemeData(
          useMaterial3: true,
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(
              seedColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 23, 88, 226)),
        ),
        home: GamePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

//________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
class MyAppState extends ChangeNotifier {
  // contient toutes les variables et les fonctions utilisées dans la page
  var Points = 301;
  List<String> playerList = <String>['Nykko', 'Lotesh']; // Liste des joueurs

  Widget _buildButton(String text, {VoidCallback? onPressed}) {
    return Expanded(
      child: TextButton(
        onPressed: onPressed ?? () => _input(text),
        child: Text(text),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _input(String text) {
    Points = Points - int.parse(text);
    print(Points.toString());
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

//________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
class GamePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var appState = context.watch<MyAppState>();

    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 229, 227),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    // Bouton de retour au menu principal
                    color: Color(0xFF5F67EA),
                    height: 100,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      child: const Text('Retour Home page'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => const HomePage()),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  for (String player in appState.playerList)
                    PlayerCard(playerName: player, playerScore: 301)
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    appState._buildButton('1'),
                    appState._buildButton('2'),
                    appState._buildButton('3'),
                    appState._buildButton('4'),
                    appState._buildButton('5'),
                    appState._buildButton('6'),
                    appState._buildButton('7'),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    appState._buildButton('8'),
                    appState._buildButton('9'),
                    appState._buildButton('10'),
                    appState._buildButton('11'),
                    appState._buildButton('12'),
                    appState._buildButton('13'),
                    appState._buildButton('14'),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    appState._buildButton('15'),
                    appState._buildButton('16'),
                    appState._buildButton('17'),
                    appState._buildButton('18'),
                    appState._buildButton('19'),
                    appState._buildButton('20'),
                    appState._buildButton('25'),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
//________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

class PlayerCard extends StatelessWidget {
  // = 1 joueur dans la partie

  const PlayerCard({
    super.key,
    required this.playerName,
    required this.playerScore,
  });

  final String playerName;
  final int playerScore;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 59, 65, 184),
      height: 100,
      width: 200,
      child: Text(
        playerScore.toString(),
        style: const TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 42,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
      ), //afficher les points en cours
    );
  }
}


I think i can do it creating a dictionary <NamePlayer> : <Score> and put  it in MyAppSate. So that every time I modify the dictionary, the PlayerCard will update.
I'm not sure for now how to do it but I think this is possible, but my question is, with my constructor PlayerCard (used in a for each in the GamePage) can I give a name or an id maybe to each widget PlayerCard that I construct? So that when I calculate the point i can say, current player is 1, so PlayerCard 1's new score is 301 - currentPointMade ?
I don't know if I'm clear but hope so :)
